# Как разбить массив по кускам и превратить его в строку?

Tags: javascript, строки, разделение-строк

У меня есть массив `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Я хочу разбить его по кускам из 5 элементов, превратив это все дело в строку таким образом(пять элементов с разделителем - перевод строки):

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вы хотите получить 2 строки из одного массива? Или как то по очереди получать первые пять элементов?

Comment: я хочу получить одну строку

Comment: Одну из 5 элементов или из всего массива?

Comment: одну строку из всего массива

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы из массива сделать строку, можно воспользоваться методом **join([sep])**

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(arr.join(','))
```

> **.join()** собирает массив в строку через заданный разделитель

Если надо вернуть ограниченное количество элементов из массива, можно сделать функцию

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function getStringFromArr(array, begin, end, sep) {
  return array.slice(begin, end).join(sep)
}

console.log(getStringFromArr(arr, 2, 7, ','));
```

#### Получение из массива строки с разделителем

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function strSep(arr, sep) {
    let first = arr.splice(0, 5).join(',');
    first += sep;
    return first + arr.splice(0).join(',')
}

console.log(strSep(arr, '\n'))
```

Эта же функция в одну строку без лишних переменных

```
function strSep(arr, sep) {
    return arr.splice(0, 5).join(',') + sep + arr.splice(0).join(',')
}
```

> Метод **.splice()** мутирует исходный массив! Если мутация не нужна, замените на **slice()**

#### Функции, возвращающие строку, разделенную заданным разделителем по 5 элементов

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
// Не мутирует исходный массив
function getFiveLine(arr, sep) {
    let result = '';
    let work = 0
    while (work < arr.length) {
        result += arr.slice(work, work + 5).join(',') + sep;
        work += 5;
    }
    return result;
}
// Мутирует исходный массив
function getFiveLineMut(arr, sep) {
  let result = '';
  while (arr.length) {
      result += arr.splice(0, 5).join(',') + sep;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getFiveLine(arr, '\n'))
console.log(getFiveLineMut(arr, '\n'))
```

При необходимости, последний символ разделитель можно удалить.
Так же все задать параметрами функции, допустим длину с 5 на 7 и сам разделитель элементов массивов

Comment: Вы не правильно поняли, я хочу получить целостную строку из массива, но при этом разделить его по кускам, как показанно в примере.

Comment: @LEON Это либо 2 строки, либо одна строка с разделителем(Каким?). Получить 2 строки в виде одной строки не получится

Comment: Снова не так поняли, из всех элементов массива я хочу сделать одну строку с разделителем

Comment: @LEON Обновил ответ

Comment: Это то что мне нужно, однако если в массиве больше 10-ти элементов, это не будет работать

Comment: @LEON Сделал так, что бы работало для любого количества элементов

Comment: Огромное спасибо за потраченное на меня время.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  //создаем массив из 50 элементов
  const arr = new Array(50).fill('').map((_, i) => i);
  console.log(
    arr
      .join(',')
      //переводим на новоую строку каждые 5 символов с помошю регулярного выражения
      .replace(/((\w+,?){5})/gm, '$1\n')
      //удаляем последние запятые в линиях
      .replace(/,\n/g, '\n'),
  );
```